# Вопрос по ссылкам на объекты

Tags: java

У меня есть программа:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyInt a = new MyInt(5);
        MyInt b = new MyInt(10);
        MyInt c = new MyInt(0);

        System.out.println("Начальные значения:");
        System.out.println("a = " + a.getNum());
        System.out.println("b = " + b.getNum());
        System.out.println("c = " + c.getNum());

        c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;

        System.out.println("Конечные значения:");
        System.out.println("a = " + a.getNum());
        System.out.println("b = " + b.getNum());
        System.out.println("c = " + c.getNum());
    }
}

class MyInt {
    private int num;

    MyInt(int n) { num = n; }

    void setNum(int n) { num = n; }
    int getNum() { return num; }
}
```

По смыслу действия во время присваивания такие:

1. `с` присваивается ссылка на `а`.
2. `а` присваивается ссылка на `b` (по скольку `а` ссылается на `b`, то и `с` должна ссылаться на `b`);
3. `b` присваивается ссылка на `с` (а по скольку `с` должна ссылаться на `b`, тогда `b` присваивается ссылка на `b`).

В результате, везде должны быть ссылки на `b` и, при выводе `getNum`, везде должно быть число 10. Но результат такой:

```
Начальные значения:
a = 5
b = 10
c = 0
Конечные значения:
a = 10
b = 5
c = 5
```

Почему такой результат? Разве непримитивным типам данных присваются не ссылки? Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Дадим названия некоторым объектам, чтобы на них было удобно строить объяснение:

```
MyInt a = new MyInt(5);  // создается объект a_obj, на который переменная a хранит ссылку
MyInt b = new MyInt(10); // создается объект b_obj, на который переменная b хранит ссылку
MyInt c = new MyInt(0);  // создается объект c_obj, на который переменная c хранит ссылку
```

Что происходит на самом деле в следующем фрагменте кода:

```
c = a; // c ссылается на a_obj
a = b; // a ссылается на b_obj
b = c; // b ссылается на a_obj
```

1. `c` присваивается ссылка на объект, на который ссылается `a`, т.е. не сама `a`, а объект на который она ссылается (объект `a_obj`)
2. `a` присваивается ссылка на объект, на который ссылается `b` (объект `b_obj`)
3. `b` присваивается ссылка на объект, на который ссылается `c` (т.е. на `a_obj`, на который начала ссылаться переменная `c` в первом пункте)

Таким образом:

1. `a` ссылается на `b_obj` (который `==` 10)
2. `b` ссылается на `a_obj` (который `==` 5)
3. `c` ссылается на `a_obj` (который `==` 5)

В итоге, объект `c_obj` остается неиспользуемым, т.к. на него никто не ссылается (т.е. счетчик ссылок на него `==` 0). В таком случае, сборщик мусора (`GC`) при первой же возможности освободит выделенную под объект `c_obj` память.

Comment: Хм... Я всегда думал, что с ссылками немного запутаннее ситуация. Спасибо, что объяснили). А не подскажете, есть ли книга по Java, где рассказывается о всех нюансах работы с переменными, ссылками, объектами и тд.?

Comment: @bukashka101 Ну, вообще, [Философия Java](http://wikijava.it-cache.net/index.php?title=%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0_1_Thinking_in_Java_4th_edition) — отличная книга по Java (посмотрите раздел _"Введение в объекты"_).