# Реализовать метод доступ с возвращаемым типом void

Tags: java, методы

Нужно реализовать такой метод без возвращаемого значения. Если нет возвращаемого значения, то мы можем "вытащить" информацию только с помощью передаваемого параметра, как я понимаю. Попытался реализовать это (метод get), не получилось. Не очень понимаю, почему не вышло, ибо String - ссылочный тип, и передается же копия ссылки.

```
public class Ex3 {
    private ArrayList<Integer> array;
    private String str;

    public Ex3(ArrayList array, String str){
        this.array = array;
        this.str=str;
    }

    public void get(String ourString){ //Попытка реализации такого метода
        ourString=str;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы изменяете ссылку на объект, а не сам объект String, но сам объект String вы не можете изменить, т.к. это immutable объект.

Comment: @Igor смотря как реализовать, если сюда отдавать непустой String, а затем полагаться на изменение его внутреннего массива байт (`byte[]`), то еще как можно, но из-за его иммутабельности такой вариант не подойдет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Причина проблемы:**

Чтобы понять причину такого поведения, нужно разобраться в принципах работы с памятью в Java:

- все объекты создаются в куче (`heap`), т.е. в общей памяти приложения;
- все переменные (в том числе, аргументы методов) хранятся на стэке (`stack`), т.е. в памяти определенного потока приложения;
- в переменных хранятся лишь ссылки на объекты из кучи (за исключением примитивов);
- при вызове метода в его аргументы просто копируются значения из переменных, которые указываются при его вызове (т.е. по факту, в них копируются адреса ссылок на объекты из кучи, на которые указывают переменные, которые передаются в аргументах вызова метода, т.е. передаются лишь копии ссылок).

Как итог, любое изменение значения (посредством применения оператора присваивания `=`) аргумента метода никоим образом не скажется на значении переменной из места вызова метода.

Возможно, [вот этот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/499737/200756) нагляднее поможет вам разобраться в вышеописанном механизме работы с памятью.

**Способы решения проблемы:**

Создать объект, обертку над полем, которое вы хотите заполнить в рамках вашего метода, ссылку на экземпляр этого объекта отдать в аргументах вызова метода:

```
public class Example {
    private static class Wrapper {
        private String field;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
        fill(wrapper);
        System.out.println(wrapper.field);
    }

    private static void fill(Wrapper wrapper) {
        wrapper.field = "some string";
    }
}
```

Опять же, стоит понимать, что в данном случае вы отдаете не `null` экземпляр объекта обертки над `String`, т.к. иначе вам просто не у какого объекта из кучи будет заполнять поле.

Точно также вы можете поступить с элементами коллекций (например, `ArrayList`), т.к. они сами являются обертками над массивом объектов (`Object[]`), т.е. в каком-то смысле они тоже `Wrapper`'ы.

Также стоит понимать, что, по факту, класс `String` сам является оберткой над массивом байт (у него имеется поле `private final byte[] value;`), предоставляющего методы для работы с ним как с символами в определенной кодировке (например, `UTF-8`).

Тем не менее, у вас нет возможности изменить содержимое байтового поля у уже существующего экземпляра `String` (так же, как в примере выше с классом `Wrapper`) в виду неизменяемости (`immutable`) экземпляров класса `String`.

Неизменяемость в рамках экземпляров класса `String` достигнута за счет того, что:

- байтовое поле инициализируется лишь один раз при создании экземпляра класса (за счет модификатора `final`);
- прямой доступ к полю отсутствует (за счет модификатора `private`, отсутствия `set`'а, а также возвращении лишь копии массива байт при вызове метода `getBytes`).

---

Заполнять поля чего-то, что итак доступно из метода, например, статического поля класса:

```
public class Example {
    private static String field;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fill();
        System.out.println(field);
    }

    private static void fill() {
        field = "some string";
    }
}
```

Не стоит злоупотреблять статикой в Java, такой пример я привел лишь для иллюстрации возможного варианта.

---

**Рекомендации:**

Если, все же, вы хотите "заполнять" поля передаваемого объекта, то метод явно лучше назвать отличным от `get` способом, например, `fill`, т.к. иначе своим наименованием он будет вводить в заблуждение читающих ваш код людей.